# Python: TKinter can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to put in place a UI comprised of 4 frames, that depend of a main window. In each frame, there will be a button. Each frame has a title/label that must appear.

There is an image background on the window, and I'm aiming to code so that the frames background are transparent (or black. This is not crucial).

My problem is that, although the mainWindow appears smoothly, the program does not seem to manage to create the frames. I have no error before running, but one after closing it.

I have read many different answers about the fact that the master has to be made available to my labels or such (and as far as I can understand, it is).

```
    from tkinter import *
    top = Tk()

    mainWindow = Canvas(top, bg = "blue", height = 500, width = 600)
    filename = PhotoImage(file="C:\matrix.png")
    background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    mainWindow.pack()
    top.mainloop()


    # fenêtre load Key
    KeyFrame = Frame(mainWindow, borderwidth = 2, relief = SUNKEN)
    KeyFrame.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 30, pady = 30)

    # fenêtre load Fichier
    FileFrame = Frame(mainWindow, borderwidth = 2, relief = SUNKEN)
    FileFrame.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    # Labels
    KeyLabel = Label(KeyFrame, text = "Choix de la matrice...",  bg = "black").pack(fill = BOTH, expand = "YES")
    FileLabel = Label(FileFrame, text = "Choix de la fichier...", bg = "black").pack(fill = BOTH, expand = "YES")
```

Here is the error I can see when I close the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH", line 15, in <module>
    KeyFrame = Frame(mainWindow, borderwidth = 2, relief = SUNKEN)

  File "PATH", line 2738, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)

  File "PATH", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed
```

Answer (score 2):

The `top.mainloop()` should be called *after* you create all widgets. Because the script does not run any lines after `mainloop()` as long as the window is open. Try placing it in the end.

Comment: Hello, I should have put it back but I already tried that, and it did not change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Move `top.mainloop()` at the very end of your program because the execution of your python program stops there and nothing below that line can be executed.

Comment: Hello, I should have put it back but I already tried that, and it did not change anything unfortunately.