# TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-button

**given below is the code to create buttons to add to the root window and creating empty functions (for now) to assign to the buttons:**

```
ml1 = Button(root, text='The Gold', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: first_madlib(root), bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml1.place(x=125, y=90)

ml2 = Button(root, text='One Dark, Stormy Night', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: second_madlib(root) , bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml2.place(x=50, y=150)

ml3 = Button(root, text='The Ring', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: third_madlib(root), bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml3.place(x=125, y=210)
```

**on execution it displays:**

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-441880b70eba> in <module>
----> 1 ml1 = Button(root, text='The Gold', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: first_madlib(root), bg='LightSkyBlue')
      2 ml1.place(x=125, y=90)
      3 
      4 ml2 = Button(root, text='One Dark, Stormy Night', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: second_madlib(root) , bg='LightSkyBlue')
      5 ml2.place(x=50, y=150)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2648             overrelief, state, width
   2649         """
-> 2650         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
   2651 
   2652     def flash(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2570         for k, v in classes:
   2571             del cnf[k]
-> 2572         self.tk.call(
   2573             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2574         for k, v in classes:

TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

I am new to Python and hence do not understand what it means. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include enough code to show how you initialized ```root``` and the main loop and how you're running it.  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249742/python-tkinter-cant-invoke-frame-command-application-has-been-destroyed I'm guessing you have those lines after you've started the mainloop()

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("320x320")

def first_madlib(root):
    print("Button 1 clicked")
def second_madlib(root):
    print("Button 2 clicked")
def third_madlib(root):
    print("Button 3 clicked")

ml1 = Button(root, text='The Gold', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: first_madlib(root), bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml1.place(x=125, y=90)

ml2 = Button(root, text='One Dark, Stormy Night', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: second_madlib(root) , bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml2.place(x=50, y=150)

ml3 = Button(root, text='The Ring', font=("Comic Sans MS", 16), command=lambda: third_madlib(root), bg='LightSkyBlue')
ml3.place(x=125, y=210) 

root.mainloop()
```

Et voilà:

[image]

```
$ python3 buttontest.py
Button 1 clicked
Button 2 clicked
Button 3 clicked
```